# C++ class inclusion issue "not type named xxx in namespace"

Tags: c++, namespaces

Here is the code -- a component class first:

```
// LoSComponent.h

namespace LoS {
    class Component: public Ref {

    public:
        Component();
        ~Component();
    };
}
```

and another class need a pointer of LoS::Component as parameter:

```
LoSStrategyPreProcessBase.h

#include "LoSComponent.h"

namespace LoS {

    namespace Strategy {

        namespace PreProcess {

            class Base {
            public:
                Base(LoS::Component* losComponent)
                {
                    this->_losComponent = losComponent;
                };
                ~Base()
                {
                };
            public:
                LoS::Component* _losComponent;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And the code above will give me the error:

```
LoSStrategyPreProcessBase.h No type named 'Component' in namespace 'LoS'
```

Any ideas that how I can get this code to complier?

Thanks in advance .

Update 1:

I tried to replace LoS::Component to ::LoSComponent  but is still getting the same error:

[image]

Update 2:

I created a simple project with 2 simple class and I found that the problem seem to be caused in header file inclusion.

The code complier && link OK:

```
LoSComponent.h

#ifndef LoSComponent_h
#define LoSComponent_h

namespace LoS {

    class Component {

    public:
        Component();
        ~Component();
    };
}


#endif /* LoSComponent_h */
```

And :

```
#ifndef LoSBase_h
#define LoSBase_h

#include "LoSComponent.h"

namespace LoS {

    namespace Stragergy {
        class Base {

        public:
            Base(LoS::Component* los){
                this->_los = los;
            };
            ~Base();
        private:
            LoS::Component* _los;
        };

    }
}

#endif /* LoSBase_h */
```

As you can see I can use LoS::Component in LoSBase.h with no error.

Then I tried to change the LoSComponent.h :

```
#ifndef LoSComponent_h
#define LoSComponent_h

#include "LoSBase.h"

namespace LoS {

    class Component {

    public:
        Component();
        ~Component();

    private:
        LoS::Stragergy::Base* _base;
    };
}


#endif /* LoSComponent_h */
```

As you can see I added a 
`#include "LoSBase.h"`

and

```
LoS::Stragergy::Base* _base;
```

and this time it fails with an error:

```
LoSComponent.h:23:14: error: no member named 'Stragergy' in namespace 'LoS'
        LoS::Stragergy::Base* _base;
        ~~~~~^


LoSBase.h:20:23: error: no type named 'Component' in namespace 'LoS'
            Base(LoS::Component* los){
                 ~~~~~^
```

Comment: Change `LoS::Component` to `::LoS::Component` or just `Component`. While in `namespace PreProcess`, `LoS::Component` implies `::PreProcess::LoS::Component` which doesn't exist.

Comment: What's the class `Ref` that `LoS::Component` derives from?   It doesn't seem to be defined anywhere, and that can cause the compiler to subsequently consider `Los::Component` is not a valid type.

Comment: @DeiDei: Write your answer in _the answer section_. It is cleverly named that way

Answer (score 0):

Change `Base(LoS::Component* losComponent)` to `Base(::LoS::Component* losComponent)`.

`::` before namespace, class or function tells compiler to look for namespace/class/function in global namespace

Comment: Thanks for your answer I tried your suggestion but is still getting the same error. (see my updated screenshot)